# How to join two different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in Sql Server which has the record of the entry and exit of a person, that entry and exit are recorded in different rows, so what I am trying to do in my query is to be able to show in a single row the entry and exit of a person, what I have tried is to put DISTINCT or GROUP BY, I thought that somehow a union in a single row would be possible but it does not and it shows me fields as null:
This is my query:

```
SELECT
    ICA.Fecha_Hora,
    Convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora,106) as 'Fecha',
    CASE
        WHEN ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = 2 THEN convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora ,108)
    END AS 'Entrada',
    CASE
        WHEN ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = 1 THEN convert(nvarchar,ICA.Fecha_Hora ,108)
    END AS 'Salida'
FROM 
    Intranet.DBO.Int_Control_Acceso ICA
        INNER JOIN Intranet.DBO.Int_Tipo_Acceso ITA ON ITA.Id_Tp_Acso = ICA.Id_Tp_Acso
        INNER JOIN Bit_V3.dbo.BIO_Programacion_Detalle BPD ON ICA.Id_IE = BPD.Id_IE
WHERE 
    CONVERT(date,ICA.Fecha_Hora) BETWEEN ISNULL('25/05/2021','01/01/2020') and ISNULL('25/05/2021',GETDATE()) AND
    CONVERT(date,BPD.FechaInicio) BETWEEN ISNULL('25/05/2021','01/01/2020') and ISNULL('25/05/2021',GETDATE()
```

This is what it returns to me:
[image]

Comment: If its just two records all the time, you could cheat and do a group by with a MIN/MAX on the end two columns.  If its a set of data, you have to do something else.  This is also assuming the final result you want looks like:  '25 May 2021', '05:57:57', '21:21:07'.

Comment: Tip: start with a query to give the just the Entry times, and then use the `APPLY` keyword to add the exit/Salida time for each row.

Comment: What do you do if an entry doesn't have an exit? Or an exit's entry was the previous day? What about the case where an exit is missing (e.g. the user entered, then entered again, then exited, maybe with a long delay in between or maybe a double tap on entry just a few milliseconds apart)?

Answer (score 0):

You can join the same table twice. For simplification, imagine this is our table:

```
CREATE TABLE UserAction (
ID int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
UserID int,
ActionType int,
ActionDateTime datetime)
```

Then, to do what you are wanting to do:

```
SELECT UserID, enter.ActionDateTime as EnterDateTime
FROM UserAction enter
JOIN UserAction exit on enter.UserID = exit.UserID
WHERE enter.ActionType = 1
AND exit.ActionType = 2
```

Of course, if you have more than one enter record and/or more than one exit record for a given user, then you have to account for that.

Comment: If you go this route, it needs to be an outer join (might have an entry with no exit), and the actiontype criteria need to be moved to the join.

Comment: Could be. Depends on the use-case and whether or not he wants to records that have an entry with no exit. That wasn't in the requirements. Just like if a user has multiple enter and exit records. And does it matter if the enter and exit aren't on the same day. Could get much more complex.